# Change to compiler 1.7 when creating a List produced errors throughout the entire project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno and Java.

I was trying to create a new list:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

This had an error and the resolution on it was along the lines of change compiler to 1.7 which I accepted. The errror on this list creation line was corrected however I now have many errors thoughout the whole project on lines that were previously working. Some examples are:

```
class GetAccountAndCubsHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<List<AccountAndCubs>>
```

Multiple markers at this line
 - The hierarchy of the type GetAccountAndCubsHandler is inconsistent
 - List cannot he resolved to a type

```
public class AccountCreationView extends Composite {
```

Multiple markers at this line
 - The hierarchy of the type AccountCreationView is inconsistent
 - Breakpoint:AccountCreationView

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String accountId;
```

First line - Multiple markers at this line
 - SuppressWarnings cannot be resolved to a type
 - The attribute valie is undefined for the annotation type SuppressWarnings

Second line - String cannot be resolved to a type

As you can imagine having my whole project adversely affected in this way is very disconcerting so any advice on how to recover would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"String cannot be resolved to a type"*

Ensure that a valid JRE or JDK is specified in your build-path.

Since you're using Eclipse, right-click on your project, then `Properties` → `Java Build Path`.

Comment: This is the problem. When I go into "Java Build Path" 1.7 is Unbound and the sub folders are "Access rules: No rules defined" and "Native library location: (none)". How do I resolve this please? As you have probably guessed I am very much a novice and am developing this for my Scout Group. Thank you very much for your help. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: While poking around I was able to find 1.6 and restored to that. Luckily that worked. My heart is now out of my stomach! Should I be upgrading to 1.7? If yes, is it safe and how do I do it? Or is there another way to define a List? Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't have a Java 7 JRE configured in the `Installed JREs` preference panel.